# Pyflink windowAll() by event-time to apply a clutering model

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink, flinkml

I'm a beginner on pyflink framework and I would like to know if my use case is possible with it ...

I need to make a tumbling windows and apply a python udf (scikit learn clustering model) on it.
The use case is :  every 30 seconds I want to apply my udf on the previous 30 seconds of data.

For the moment I succeeded in consume data from a kafka in streaming but then I'm not able to create a 30seconds window on a non-keyed stream with the python API.

Do you know some example for my use case ? Do you know if the pyflink API allow this ?

Here my first shot :

```
from pyflink.common import Row
from pyflink.common.serialization import JsonRowDeserializationSchema, JsonRowSerializationSchema
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.connectors import FlinkKafkaConsumer, FlinkKafkaProducer
from pyflink.common.watermark_strategy import TimestampAssigner, WatermarkStrategy
from pyflink.common import Duration

import time

from utils.selector import Selector
from utils.timestampAssigner import KafkaRowTimestampAssigner

# 1. create a StreamExecutionEnvironment
env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
# the sql connector for kafka is used here as it's a fat jar and could avoid dependency issues
env.add_jars("file:///flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.11-1.14.0.jar")

deserialization_schema = JsonRowDeserializationSchema.builder() \
    .type_info(type_info=Types.ROW_NAMED(["labelId","freq","timestamp"],[Types.STRING(),Types.DOUBLE(),Types.STRING()])).build()


kafka_consumer = FlinkKafkaConsumer(
    topics='events',
    deserialization_schema=deserialization_schema,
    properties={'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'})



# watermark_strategy = WatermarkStrategy.for_bounded_out_of_orderness(Duration.of_seconds(5))\
#     .with_timestamp_assigner(KafkaRowTimestampAssigner())

ds = env.add_source(kafka_consumer)
ds.print()
ds = ds.windowAll()
# ds.print()

env.execute()
```

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner (file:/home/dorian/dataScience/pyflink/pyflink_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyflink/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar) to field java.util.Properties.serialVersionUID
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dorian/dataScience/pyflink/project/__main__.py", line 35, in <module>
    ds = ds.windowAll()
AttributeError: 'DataStream' object has no attribute 'windowAll'
```

Thx

Comment: You said you need to make a thumbling windows but you use .windowAll(). You doing it just for tests or there is a confusion? And you can make your stream keyed by using `keyBy()`.

Comment: hmm yeah maybe I misunderstand something, It seems possible for me to make a thumbling windows on a non_stream so with windowAll(), at leats in java : 
```
DataStream<Integer> globalResults = resultsPerKey
    .windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
    .process(new TopKWindowFunction());
```

Comment: Yes I think your example `resultsPerKey .windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))` should work. Be aware that in case of non-keyed streams, your original stream will not be split into multiple logical streams and all the windowing logic will be performed by a single task, i.e. with parallelism of 1. If your stream is big you can have some performance issues.

Comment: it seems impossible in Pyflink 'AttributeError: 'DataStream' object has no attribute 'windowAll' ' .
Could It be not implemented yet ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PyFlink. I can't find any mention of `.windowAll()` in documentation for python [window assigners](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/python/datastream/operators/windows/#window-assigners)

Comment: its `window_all` for pyflink